# Options for caching client-side requests?

Tags: 2013, javascript

Does Sharepoint 2013 offer any options for caching certain client-side requests for different clients (like ASP.NET cache)? I'm already using `localStorage`, but that only caches data for a single client.

I'm looking to build a solution like this:

```
Javascript request -> Browser cache -> Server cache -> Database
```

But if possible, do the whole thing from the front-end.

I understand the security implications: storing data to the server cache would be reasonable via a request, not posted back data.